How to fix unprofessional letter spacing in Microsoft Excel?
When I print or export a Microsoft Excel document as a PDF file, the letter spacing is irregular. On screen, the text shows good but not on PDF files or the printed copy.
It is reproducible with Arial, Calibri and even using the latest  font Aptos. It is not a OpenType, Acrobat Reader or Apple Preview display issue. It is an Excel bug, which has existed for years! It is NOT reproducible in MS Word or any other Apps like Numbers, Indesign. Microsoft Excel is not a desktop publishing software, but the font rendering is embarrassing! I am using Excel for Mac Version 16.89.1
How can I fix letter spacing when I export or print an Excel document? I have attached a screenshot as reference

More examples, taken from the Microsoft Community Forum.



Can you give specific examples of the bad letter spacing in your examples above? To be honest, I see nothing  unprofessional in the examples.

@IconDaemon I have added another example. It is more than obvious. If you don't see that the letter spacing is irregular, I don't know what to say.
